# Counting the elements that can be divided by 2 in recursion method

Tags: java, recursion

I have a task (Homework) to count the number of elements in the array that can be divided by 2, I need to do it in a recursion way in order to improve performance. The problem is my counter does not keep the value and return only 1 instead of the number of elements that can be divided by 2 in my example it should return 7

You can look at the code that tried remember I need it to do it in recursion way not regular way with for loop which much easier...

```
public class Sample1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] array = {2,4,6,8,14,12,14};
        System.out.println(what(array));
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param a an array of of numbers
     * @return the number of numbers that can divided by 2
     */
    public static int what (int []a){
        return countingPairNumberes (a, 0, a.length - 1,0);

    }
    /**
     *
     * @param a an array of of numbers
     * @param lo the begining of the array
     * @param hi the end of the array
     * @return the number of numbers that can divided by 2
     */
    private static int countingPairNumberes (int [] a, int lo, int hi , int sum)
    {
        int counter = sum;
        if (lo <= hi) {
            if(a[lo] % 2 == 0)
                counter++;
            countingPairNumberes (a, lo+1, hi ,counter);

        }

        return counter;

    }


}
```

My expected results that counter will be 7 and this what I am going to print on the screen, but I am getting the value 1 instead.

Comment: You don't do anything with the result of the recursive call.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that I should not use the results or I have an error in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass `sum` as a parameter to the recursive method. And you shouldn't ignore the result of the recursive call.

The count of even numbers in a given array is the count of the even numbers of the sub-array you get after removing the first element, with the optional addition of 1, if the removed element is even.

```
/**
 *
 * @param a an array of of numbers
 * @return the number of numbers that can divided by 2
 */
public static int what (int []a){
    return countingPairNumberes (a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

/**
 *
 * @param a an array of of numbers
 * @param lo the begining of the array
 * @param hi the end of the array
 * @return the number of numbers that can divided by 2
 */
private static int countingPairNumberes (int [] a, int lo, int hi)
{
    if (lo <= hi) {
        int counter = countingPairNumberes (a, lo+1, hi);
        if(a[lo] % 2 == 0)
            counter++;
        return counter;

    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```